# Print Win32::OLE debug message

Tags: perl, win32ole

Here is the snippet of my Perl code, it launches MYAPP on one Win7 machine but not on other Win7 machine, I could launch MYAPP manually without any issues.

```
my $RC = false;
$X = Win32::OLE->new('MYAPP.Application');
if ($X == null)
{
   print "\nError launching MYAPP";
   return $RC;
}
```

how do I make it to print the reason for failure? something like:

```
$X = Win32::OLE->new('MYAPP.Application') or die "cannot launch MYAPP because ____";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `use Win32::OLE; $Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;` update your post with the information you get.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, it prints as Win32::OLE(0.1601) error 0x80070005: "Access is denied", seems "user" used in script has no access to MYAPP.